# Combine a bunch of data files in R

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr

Sample

```
fileABC=data.frame("id" = c(1:10),
                   "var1" = c("5*",8,1,4,"3*",5,6,7,"7*",1),
                   "var2" = c(7,4,6,"1*","8*",2,0,7,"0*",1))
fileQWE=data.frame("id" = c(1:10),
                   "var1" = c(7,"5*",8,1,4,"3*",5,"7*",6,2),
                   "var2" = c("8*",2,0,7,7,4,6,"1*","0*",1))
var1=c(fileABC$var1,fileQWE$var1)
var2=c(fileABC$var2,fileQWE$var2)
WANT = data.frame("id"=c(1:10,1:10)
                  "var1"=var1,
                  "var2"=var2,
                  "source"=c(rep("fileABC",10), rep("fileQWE",10)))
```

I have fileABC and fileQWE. Firstly of all, these files contain random * that I want to eliminate. Secondly, I want to read in R both of the files and save them as fileABC and fileQWE. Then I want to create data frame WANT which combines var1 from both files and var2 from both files and makes new variable "source" that equals to fileABC or fileQWE depending on where it comes from. I included my attempt but as you can run and see it does not work.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); bind_rows(lst(fileABC, fileQWE), .id = 'source')`

Comment: @akrun that is great actually, do you know how to remove "*"

Comment: I posted a solution, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows` and get the numeric elements extracted with `parse_number`

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(lst(fileABC, fileQWE), .id = 'source') %>% 
       mutate_at(vars(starts_with("var")), 
            list(~ readr::parse_number(as.character(.))))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "^file"))
out <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lst1, source = names(lst1)))
row.names(out) <- NULL
out[2:3] <- lapply(out[2:3], function(x) as.numeric(sub("*", "", x, fixed = TRUE)))
```

---

If we want to read directly from `.csv` file (assuming files are in the working directory)

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
names(files) <- str_remove(files, "\\.csv")
library(readr)
imap_dfr(files, ~ read.csv(.x) %>%
                 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("var")), 
                    list(~ readr::parse_number(.))) %>%
                 mutate(source = .y))
```

Comment: just being curious but say I wanted to read in fileABC and fileQWE from .csv files how could I modify this code I tried but to no avail..@akrun

Comment: @bvowe Are the names of the .csv also `fileQWE.csv` etc.